# How to get the View for a class, that extends a class that extends Fragment/activity etc

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-lifecycle, class-extensions

I am having a problem were I have:

class x that extends y

and class y that extends Fragment

I wan to be able to do things in x that for eg get a textview with ID and change the text.
To do this, I must get the view but I get problems.
I have tried Super.getView, and I have tried to save the view in y and access from x but it does not work.

Why is this?

edit: example code:

```
public x extends fragment{

}

public y extends x{
    public y(){
         eg TextView t = this.getView().getById(...)
         which will fail as cant get the view
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would save the `TextView` as a protected var in the class that extends fragment so that you have access to it from its subclasses:

```
public class x extends Fragment {
    protected TextView myTextView;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        myTextView = view.findViewById(...);
    }
}

public class y extends x {
    public void y() {
        if (myTextView != null) {
            myTextView...
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that it will only have the myTextView assigned after `onViewCreated` is called on that fragment, but you can check if it has been defined (it's not null) before doing whatever you have to.

P.S.: In the case of extending an `Activity` it could be assigned in `onCreate` method by calling the `findViewById` method of that activity:

```
public class x extends Activity {
    protected TextView myTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ....

        myTextView = findViewById(...);
    }
}
```